# What's the recommended method for adding javascript functions in Ember-cli project?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to create a library containing general-purpose javascript functions and classes for use in any Ember object in an Ember-cli project.  What's the recommended procedure for doing this?

Comment: You would put them in your [/utils](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#utilities) directory

Comment: Is this for you own project, or for sharing?

Comment: This is for my own project.

Answer (score 2):

You should generate new util in Ember CLI:

```
ember g util your-name
```

Then you can import it using:

```
import yourName from '../utils/your-name'
```

Comment: Is the from '../utils/your-name' relative to location of the comsumming object?  I tried what you suggested before posting this question.  I kept  getting a "could not find module error."  I posted another question regarding this.  Please search 34167418.  Do you know what's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an addon is the Ember-CLI-preferred method of doing that. Addons can be published to NPM and installed in Ember CLI projects using NPM. This makes it incredibly easy to share code. [There's a guide for developing addons](http://ember-cli.com/extending/#developing-addons-and-blueprints) on the Ember CLI site.

Comment: But this is just a simple utility function that's of no value to anyone else, so publishing to NPM seems a bit inappropriate.

Comment: I may have misread your question. I thought you wanted a way to share between different Ember CLI projects. If you want a function for just one project, then a utility is the way to go.

Comment: I can't get import to work no matter what I tried.  Please see post 34167418.